# Apposition between the noun and the participial phrase

Tags: appositives

There’s “a glass broken by me.” But I want to use an apposition between “glass” and “broken” as in sentence one.

1. A glass, my favorite one, broken by me is on the floor.
2. A glass broken by me, my favorite one, is on the floor.

Sentence one means an intact glass is my favorite one.

Sentence two means a broken glass is my favorite.

Am I understanding correctly? I’m afraid that two sentences may mean a broken glass is my favorite because participial phrases modify nouns anyway.

Edited: It’s not a prepositional phrase. It’s a participial phrase.

Comment: I don't know nothin' about *apposition*, but I can tell you that neither of those sentences would be uttered by a native speaker of English.  To the best of my ability (I am a native speaker) I understand both to mean that you are standing, sadly looking at the fragments of what used to be your favourite glass lying on the floor.

Comment: @High Performance Mark 

Comment: If the glass is broken, how can it be intact? Are you asking whether the first sentence means the glass was your favorite before you broke it and the second means that it was your favorite after you broke it? I don't believe any native English speaker would agree with this interpretation of these sentences.

Comment: The glass, my favorite one, lay where I broke it on the floor. That would be a "clean" apposition.

Comment: Leaving aside the unnaturalness of your examples, "my favorite one" is not an appositive NP. Appositives NPs are specifying, not ascriptive.

Comment: *I broke a glass, my favorite one.*

Comment: _A broken glass lies on the floor. **My favourite glass**. I broke it, and haven't had the heart to sweep the pieces up yet._